# Angular:.Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema

Tags: angular, angularjs, webpack

I just startred programing and in my first project on Angular i tried to use ng serve an then this error come out:

```
initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.cache.cacheDirectory: The provided value "D:\\!!!!YoProgramo2\\!!!! Trabajos Argentina programa\\Pruebas Angular\\Prueba 
proyecto\\Prueba\\.angular\\cache\\13.3.5\\angular-webpack" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
   -> Base directory for the cache (defaults to node_modules/.cache/webpack).
 - configuration.context: The provided value "D:\\!!!!YoProgramo2\\!!!! Trabajos Argentina programa\\Pruebas Angular\\Prueba proyecto\\Prueba" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
   -> The base directory (absolute path!) for resolving the `entry` option. If `output.pathinfo` is set, the included pathinfo is shortened to this directory.
 - configuration.module.rules[9] should be one of these:
   ["..." | object { assert?, compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, issuerLayer?, layer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, scheme?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }, ...]
   -> A rule.
   Details:
    * configuration.module.rules[5].rules[0].oneOf[0].include[0]: The provided value "D:\\!!!!YoProgramo2\\!!!! Trabajos Argentina programa\\Pruebas Angular\\Prueba proyecto\\Prueba\\src\\styles.css" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
    * configuration.module.rules[5].rules[0].oneOf[0].include[0]: The provided value "D:\\!!!!YoProgramo2\\!!!! Trabajos Argentina programa\\Pruebas Angular\\Prueba proyecto\\Prueba\\src\\styles.css" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
    * configuration.module.rules[6].rules[0].oneOf[0].include[0]: The provided value "D:\\!!!!YoProgramo2\\!!!! Trabajos Argentina programa\\Pruebas Angular\\Prueba proyecto\\Prueba\\src\\styles.css" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
    * configuration.module.rules[6].rules[0].oneOf[0].include[0]: The provided value "D:\\!!!!YoProgramo2\\!!!! Trabajos Argentina programa\\Pruebas Angular\\Prueba proyecto\\Prueba\\src\\styles.css" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
    * configuration.module.rules[7].rules[0].oneOf[0].include[0]: The provided value "D:\\!!!!YoProgramo2\\!!!! Trabajos Argentina programa\\Pruebas Angular\\Prueba proyecto\\Prueba\\src\\styles.css" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
    * configuration.module.rules[7].rules[0].oneOf[0].include[0]: The provided value "D:\\!!!!YoProgramo2\\!!!! Trabajos Argentina programa\\Pruebas Angular\\Prueba proyecto\\Prueba\\src\\styles.css" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
    * configuration.module.rules[8].rules[0].oneOf[0].include[0]: The provided value "D:\\!!!!YoProgramo2\\!!!! Trabajos Argentina programa\\Pruebas Angular\\Prueba proyecto\\Prueba\\src\\styles.css" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
    * configuration.module.rules[8].rules[0].oneOf[0].include[0]: The provided value "D:\\!!!!YoProgramo2\\!!!! Trabajos Argentina programa\\Pruebas Angular\\Prueba proyecto\\Prueba\\src\\styles.css" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
    * configuration.module.rules[9].rules[0].oneOf[0].include[0]: The provided value "D:\\!!!!YoProgramo2\\!!!! Trabajos Argentina programa\\Pruebas Angular\\Prueba proyecto\\Prueba\\src\\styles.css" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
    * configuration.module.rules[9].rules[0].oneOf[0].include[0]: The provided value "D:\\!!!!YoProgramo2\\!!!! Trabajos Argentina programa\\Pruebas Angular\\Prueba proyecto\\Prueba\\src\\styles.css" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
 - configuration.output.path: The provided value "D:\\!!!!YoProgramo2\\!!!! Trabajos Argentina programa\\Pruebas Angular\\Prueba proyecto\\Prueba\\dist\\prueba" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
   -> The output directory as **absolute path** (required).
See "C:\Users\esteban\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-jt7xXe\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

i dont really undestand whats happening, i checked the styles confing at the angular.json and it this:

```
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
```

and both the styles.css and app.component.css are empty, i don't have any code there.
I looked at the webpack.config.js and the code in there is this one:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your path. Exclamation marks (!) are not tolerated at the moment. Move the project folder to path without exclamation marks is your solution.

Wrong:
D:\**!!!!**YoProgramo2\**!!!**

Correct:
D:\YoProgramo2\yourProject