# Angular Webpack configuration does not match API schema

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular latest version. When I am typing in terminal command to run Angular app (`ng serve`) it shows me error and stuck at generating browser application bundles

Here is the error:

> An unhandled exception occurred: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema

Angular.json :

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/my-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "89a1298e-b0c6-4aa3-ab9c-f7db949d130e"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the contents of your angular.json file.

Comment: Alright, edited @HereticMonkey

Comment: I should have been more clear, even though [ask] mentions it, but all code should be in the question itself, not only on an external site.

Comment: @HereticMonkey StackOverflow doesn't let me to copy paste code same as original

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: @HereticMonkey Alright, edited

Comment: pls provid the full error log. Angular shall give you the path to the log in the error message
check if path is not an issue: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75283719/9993775